# awk: Iterate through content of a large list of files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

So, I have about 60k-70k vCard-Files and want to check (or, at this point, count), which vCards contain a mail address (EMAIL;INTERNET:me@my-domain.com)

I tried to pass the output of find to awk, but I just get awk to work with the files list, not with every files content. How can I get awk to do so? I tried several combinations of find, xargs and awk, but I don't get it to work properly.

Thanks for your help,
Wolle

Comment: To begin with lets see what did you try to do?  Post whatever you tried.

Comment: find ./ -iname "*.vcf" | xargs -i awk '/EMAIL.+@/' {} or
awk '/EMAIL.+@/' $(find ./ -iname "*.vcf"...
And some ultra complex combinations I can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use `grep` for this.

- If you want to extract adresses from the files:

  ```
  grep -rio "EMAIL;INTERNET:.*@[a-z0-9-]*\.[a-z]*" *
  ```

  Use `cut`, `sed` or `awk` to remove the leading `EMAIL;INTERNET:`:

  ```
  ... | cut -d: -f2
  ... | sed "s/.*://"
  ... | awk -F: '{print $2}'
  ```
- If you want the names of the files containing a particular address:

  ```
  grep -ril "EMAIL;INTERNET:me@my-domain\.com" *
  ```

If `grep` can't process that many files at once, drop the `-r` option and try with `find` and `xargs`:

```
find /start/dir -name "*.vcf" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} grep -io "..." {}
```

Comment: This works, but dies at some point while going through 70k files :(

Comment: Which command dies, at which point, and what is the error code/message? Are all .vcf files located in the same directory?

Comment: No, there is a directory structure... Grep dies because of not enough virtual memory...

Answer (score 0):

`grep` recursive can do this

```
grep -r 'EMAIL.+@'
```